# SQL query for update data into table db

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in a database like this:

```
ID,Name,Val,Pos. 
01,ValueN1,10,0
01,ValueN2,5,1
01,ValueN3,6,2
01,ValueN4,7,3
01,ValueN5,10,4
```

I need to add a value: `01, ValueN6, 10, 3`

The column `Pos` is a key so I need to rewrite all the values (I suppose). The result I need is :

```
01,ValueN1,10,0
01,ValueN2,5,1
01,ValueN3,6,2
01,ValueN6,10,3
01,ValueN4,7,4
01,ValueN5,10,5
```

There is a way? If I simply add the value I get an error of duplication key because pos=3 already exist.

Comment: You will need to `UPDATE` all the rows which would be *after* the row first, and change their position, and then `INSERT` the value. You'll want to ensure that you do it in a transaction, so that you can roll the whole thing back in the event of an error.

Comment: Though, if `Pos` is a *key* then I would suggest it's not a good candidate for it; a (primary) key's value should not be changing as otherwise maintaining referential integrity becomes a nightmare.

Comment: This would be cause for concern, a *key* should not need to change to accommodate a new row.

Comment: If `Pos` *is* a (Primary) Key, is it referenced by any foreign key constraints? If so, then this becomes a giant can of worms.

Comment: I need to add the row but with a specific pos value. Pos isn't the primary key.

Comment: So why do state, *"The column `Pos` is a Key"* @GianfrancoVrech .

Comment: The value of Pos is an external key. Used for reference in another table. Now the data from one table to the other are not correct, so I wanto to allign them.

Comment: *"Used for reference in another table."* So updating the value of `pos` is going to cause referential integrity problems...

Comment: Pos value can be 0 to 8, Now In this table I have values from 0 to 7 beacuse one value is missing. I have to add the value and put in order the pos value.

Comment: So is `pos` actually a foreign key to a *different* table?

Answer (score 0):

From the above discussion, it sounds like you have a UNIQUE constraint defined the Pos column. In that case, you should be able to adjust the other values to accommodate the insert as folows.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE YourTable
SET Pos = Pos + 1
WHERE Pos >= 3

INSERT YourTable (ID, Name, Val, Pos)
VALUES ('01', 'ValueN6', 10, 3)

COMMIT
```

I presume the "3" and other values will be parameterized in your logic.

If in fact it is referenced as a foreign key from another table, you will need to first verify that the foreign key definition is defined with the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` option.

Side note: If your design uses the same column for both ordering and referential integrity, it may be time to rethink that design.

Comment: Just repeating the suggestion here that a transaction should really be used here as well to ensure that all the changes, or none of them, are applied.

Comment: The DB is not mine. The first version of the DB have one less value from the actual version, so I need to update the data now. The external key is already ok. For this I have a data misalignment.

Comment: "*The external key is already ok. For this I have a data misalignment*" - If that is the case, you may need to temporarily disable or delete the foreign key constraint (if one is actually defined) before you run the update, and then re-enable / recreate it afterwards.

Comment: I think the final solution is take the values I have, destroy the field and make them new with the right values.